# Writing to a BYTEA field - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x98

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, binary-data

I'm writing binary data to a `BYTEA` field in a UTF8 database.

When I run the query through a PHP/PDO prepared statement, I get the error:

```
FATAL: SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x98
```

Any idea why it's treating binary data as if it should be utf8 encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the solution is that PG doesn't allow binary data to be passed as a regular 'string' value, it has to be treated as a special 'large object'.

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, $field_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```